# 和这个白人女子, 在鸟不下蛋的地点. Hanging out in the middle of nowhere with this white girl

Tags: colloquialisms

Does anyone know if this colloquial phrase "鸟不下蛋的地点" is always taken as "middle of nowhere"?

Also I have started a fun sort of instagram account to try to learn how to write Chinese that I would speak - https://www.instagram.com/p/B2vXdnYFzTJ/

Comment: A place birds don't want to live too, generally, no roads, no radio signals, no humans, and even no animals. 荒芜人烟，人迹罕至。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know if this colloquial phrase "鸟不下蛋的地点" is always taken as "middle of nowhere"?

I think the answer is 'yes'. It's a figure of speech. It could be taken as a euphemism for "鸟不拉屎的地点", which is frequently used in informal speech.

Literally, 鸟不下蛋的地点 is the place where birds won't lay their eggs; 鸟不拉屎的地点 where birds won't defecate.